# Allow caller optional flags for returns

Tags: c++, c++20

Checking return flags is generally very important. But, when you don't need to based on meeting pre-conditions, the syntax gets unnecessarily ugly.

This class allows returning a value with flags that the caller can ignore.

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template <class T, class U>
struct retval {
    T val;
    U flags;
    ~retval() = default;
    retval() = default;
    retval(T v) : val{v}, flags{} {}
    retval(T v, U u) : val{v}, flags{u} {}
    retval(const retval&) = default;
    retval(retval&&) = default;

    retval& operator=(const retval&)=default;
    retval& operator=(retval&&)=default;

    operator std::tuple<T&, U&> () { return as_tuple(); }

    operator T () { return val; }

    std::tuple<T&, U&> as_tuple() { return {val, flags}; }
};
```

Some usage examples:

```cpp
retval<int, bool> foo(int x) {
    if (x >= 0)
    {
        return {2*x, true};
    }
    return {-2*x, false};
}

// just return the first arg
int goo1(int x)
{
    return foo(x);
}

// use tie to grab args (needs the cvt to tuple<&,&>)
int goo2(int x)
{
    int y;
    bool z;
    std::tie(y, z) = foo(x);
    return y;
}

// using get -- this is fairly ugly
int goo2b(int x)
{
    return std::get<0>(foo(x).as_tuple());
}


// Structured binding declarations 
int goo3(int x)
{
    auto [y, z] = foo(x);
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the idea.  You want to be able to ignore the supplementary information being returned and keep just the main value.

But I think using a `tuple` is just going out of your way to be complicated.  It's not needed at all.  Rather, just give two public fields of that type.

Allow aggregate initialization to work (automatically).
Allow structured binding to work (automatically).

The *only* thing you are adding is an implicit conversion to grab the first value.

```
template <class T, class U>
struct retval {
    T val;
    U flags;
    operator T () { return val; }
};
```

That is, delete everything that merely added complexity without doing anything that wasn't happening already, or is automatically provided.

Now you could get fancier to make it more efficient if `T` is not a trivial or built-in type.  Prevent copying where it safely can, by overloading it for lvalue and rvalue objects.

```
    operator T& () & { return val; }
    operator T () && { return std::move(val); }
```

Assuming I got that right (not tested, just banged out) then if you write

```
void bar (const std::string&);
void baz (std::string_view);
retval<std::string,int> foo (int placeholder);
    ⋮
std::string ans = foo(1);
```

it will *move* the principle value out of the structure before destroying it.  But if you write:

```
auto result= foo(2);
std::string value = result;
/* or */  bar(result);
```

then it will use a reference to the string that lives in the structure you decided to keep. But

```
baz(result);  /* or */
baz(foo(3));
```

still won't work because it's a double user-defined conversion.

Answer (score 0):

### Naming:

`retval` would be better named something like `[specific_function]_result` where the `[specific_function]` is the name of the function whose return value it is (e.g. `std::from_chars` and `std::from_chars_result`).

---

### Compiler generated code:

```
~retval() = default;
retval() = default;
retval(T v) : val{v}, flags{} {}
retval(T v, U u) : val{v}, flags{u} {}
retval(const retval&) = default;
retval(retval&&) = default;

retval& operator=(const retval&)=default;
retval& operator=(retval&&)=default;
```

The compiler should generate most of these for us; we don't need to specify them explicitly.

We can use aggregate initialization to initialize a `retval`. We can specify the default flags value in the declaration to ensure it's always initialized: `U flags = {};`.

---

### Unnecessary tuples:

```
operator std::tuple<T&, U&> () { return as_tuple(); }
std::tuple<T&, U&> as_tuple() { return {val, flags}; }
```

Structured binding can be used on a struct. So there's really no reason to convert to a tuple in the examples.

---

### Avoid implicit conversions:

```
operator std::tuple<T&, U&> () { return as_tuple(); }
operator T () { return val; }
```

Implicit conversions are nearly always a bad idea (they're unclear and error-prone). Use `explicit` conversion operators, or simply delete these functions, as they are unnecessary. If we want to use only the first argument, we can simply do:

```
return foo(x).val;
```

---

### Use assertions to document reasoning:

If we're relying on logic to reason that we can ignore a particular value, it's better to make that explicit in the code using an assertion.

---

So:

```
template<class T, class F>
struct retval {
    T value;
    F flags = {};
};

retval<double, bool> foo() { return { 1.0, true }; }

double bar() {
    auto [value, flags] = foo();
    assert(flags);
    return value;
}
```